# R: Testing a variable that possibly doesn't exist

Tags: r, if-statement, logic, conditional-statements

I assume this is a common problem but haven't been able to find an answer to this question. Let's assume I have the following list:

```
myList <- list(
  apple = 15,
  orange = NULL
)
```

I want to test its vectors for values, although I **cannot be sure that these vectors exist** when i perform the test.

```
if(myList$apple > 1) print("Y") else print("N")
if(myList$orange > 1) print("Y") else print("N")
if(myList$banana == "plenty") print("Y") else print("N")
```

This obviously doesn't work

```
Error in if (myList$orange > 1) print("Y") else print("N") :  argument is of length zero
Error in if (myList$banana == "plenty") print("Y") else print("N") : argument is of length zero
```

However, for I want to avoid nested testing with `exists()` for reasons that would require too much detail. So my question is: **Can a test on a variable that possibly doesn't exist be performed in only one conditional statement?**

Thanks

**EDIT:** Answer by @d.b works for numerical values. Changed my question to find a generic solution for several data types.

Comment: Try with `is.null`

Comment: `if (ifelse(is.null(myList), FALSE, ifelse(my$List$apple > 1, TRUE, FALSE)) print("Y")`

Answer (score 1):

Use `max` with appropriate value.

```
max(0, NULL)
#[1] 0
```

In your case you could choose `1`

```
if(max(myList$apple, 1) > 1) print("Y") else print("N")
#[1] "Y"
if(max(myList$orange, 1) > 1) print("Y") else print("N")
#[1] "N"
if(max(myList$banana, 1) > 1) print("Y") else print("N")
#[1] "N"
```

Or you could use `max` with the logical itself to apply to other data types

```
max(c(myList$apple > 1, 0)) == 1
#[1] TRUE
max(c(myList$orange > 1, 0)) == 1
#[1] FALSE
max(c(myList$banana == "plenty", 0)) == 1
#[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Very nice, this works on my example, but is there something generic that would work for other data types?

Comment: Seems like `if("plenty" %in% myList$banana) print("Y") else print("N")` works for strings.